# Matlab 3D to 2D with Principal Component Analysis (PCA)

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d, pca, svd

I want to do PCA on this 3D matrix:

```
data=[5 4 5; 5 3 0; 1 2 2];
```

PCA should return two components, like 3D to 2D, to plot the data on a graph.

What I've tried:

```
data=[5 4 5; 5 3 0; 1 2 2];
x= princomp(data');
x
```

But 'x' returns a 3D, instead of a 2D matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you have a 3D result. I think you have a result of dimension *pxp* when your data is *nxp*, which is normal. See [the doc](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html?requestedDomain=true).